# How to get all rows (without soft deleted) from a table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use laravel 5.3

I use this :https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

My laravel eloquent is like this :

```
$data = Employee::select('id', 'name', 'salary', 'description')
                ->find($id);
```

My model is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent; 
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
class Employee extends Eloquent
{
    use HybridRelations;  
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    public $table = 'employees';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    ...
}
```

The problem is, when executed, the soft deleted items appears there. What is wrong?

Comment: you need to exclude them in selection

Comment: @Panda, What do you mean?

Comment: Did you add the $table->softDeletes() in your migration?

Comment: Soft delete means it don't delete the document from the database (may be adds another field '{isDeleted:true}'), so you may need to pass another parameter in the selection to not select any document if it is having isDeleted true, post your example document here for more understanding

Comment: @stefansixx1, I use mongodb. It's not need migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong trait `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` only works for the Laravel Eloquent models.

For Jenssegers\Mongodb you need to use:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toArray()` method in `Employee` Class.

```
function toArray() {
    return [
        'id'        =>    $this->id,
        'name'      =>    $this->name,
        'salary'    =>    $this->salary,
         ...etc // dont put deleted_at here
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had add it. But it does not work. The soft deleted items still appears there

Comment: try this : `$data = Employee::find($id)` without using the `select`

Comment: It's the same. It does not work. toArray method used for what?

Comment: it used to form the data returned from the `Model`, by default it will return the `fallible` parameters

Comment: I had find the problem. See another answer